# convert output row to column in mysql based on id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case, union

How to convert output row to column in mysql. I am trying to fetch same thing based on two different where cause. Below are two condition.

1) ReportType='FinalReport'

2) ReportType='InterimReport'

Below is my query

```
SELECT ReportID,PackageID,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '1' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '2' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '3' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '4' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check4,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '5' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check5,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '6' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check6,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '7' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check7,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '8' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check8,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '9' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check9,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '10' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check10,
         ReportType as reporttype
FROM sla_package WHERE PackageID = '134' and ReportType='FinalReport' UNION

SELECT ReportID,PackageID,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '1' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check12,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '2' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check22,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '3' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check32,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '4' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check42,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '5' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check52,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '6' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check62,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '7' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check72,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '8' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check82,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '9' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check92,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CheckID = '10' THEN CheckID ELSE NULL END) AS check102,
         ReportType as reporttype2
FROM sla_package WHERE PackageID = '134' and ReportType='InterimReport'
```

and it's output is as below

[image]

But I want output as

```
 ReportID1 PackageID check1 check2 check3 check4 check5 check6 check7 check8 check9 check10 reporttype1 RepoerID2 check11 check12 check13 check14 check15 check16 check17 check18 check19 check110  reporttype2
   2192      134       NULL   NULL   3      NULL   5      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL    FinalReport 5693      NULL    NULL    3       NULL    5       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        InterimRepo
```

Comment: i have a hard time believing it that the query gives you to top result without using `GROUP BY ReportID,PackageID`.. Also this query is ANSI SQL **invalid** because you can't mix non aggregate columns with aggregate columns without using GROUP BY..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am trying to migrate data from my old application database to new CRM database. And both structure are different.

Comment: The technique you need is called *pivoting.* It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL.

Comment: @O.Jones its not that bad unless you need a dynamic pivot “range” that you would need two queries